# Fetching data by Timestamp (latest first) in Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm doing something like a social networking site where user can post, comment and add friends.

I have common table for posts as `status_update` in Mysql:

```
create table status_update(
id int(10) not null primary key auto_increment, 
user_id int(10),
status_post varchar(1000),
image varchar(500),
video_link varchar(500),
event_time timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
);
```

This is common for all users. I want to fetch data depending on the timestamp, where last update being the latest...

And also there is one option to fetch data in reverse order, but I'm stuck on knowing how to fetch according to stored timestamp.

PS-Something like Facebook...how your and your friends feeds are displayed on your wall.

Answer (score 3):

try using a simple `order by` statement

```
$sql = "select * from status_update order by event_time asc"
```

For most recent posts/status updates, use `ORDER BY DESC`

```
$sql = "select * from status_update order by event_time desc"
```

This will place the rows with the newest timestamp at the top of the result set returned by the database call

Answer (score 2):

You can ask your Mysql database to return ordered result with the SQL clause ORDER BY and the parameters ASC or DESC

in your case the sql query will look like

```
SELECT * FROM status_update ORDER BY event_time DESC
```